# Duplicate id_token in Cookie after oAuth login

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We configured Gloo API Gateway to use Azure AD for oAuth authentication.
This is working as expected and after the user is logged in I get the `id_token` as cookie.
After some time however (I wish I knew the origin) a duplicate cookie is also set for a deeper path without a value.

[image: Duplicated cookie]

In the request headers both cookie values are sent to my API. I could loop over the cookie values in my application and use the one with a value. But I'd like to know how I can prevent this second cookie from appearing.

Comment: Hi @Tomas, In your sign out function you can write a code to clear the session cookie as it  is browser level issue.I hope this [document](https://forums.asp.net/t/2133186.aspx?Delete+session+cookies+) helps.Please let me know if you still need any more help.

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity I'm not sure if that would help. I'm also having this issue when I revisit the same endpoint, without logout, after a few hours.

Comment: @Tomas could you run the same scenario under the browser developer tools and check for the api, which is returning duplicate cookie with the path as /v1/auth. once you find it, then you will have to debug the corresponding API in the server end on why it is returning duplicate cookie.

Comment: Hi @Tomas,Please reply to above comment if you are still looking for help?